# Unity OneSignal SDK : Application not opening then I click on push notification

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, onesignal

Application on phone is closed.
When I click on received notification from OneSignal my Unity app not opening.

How to open an application on notification click in OneSignal Unity project?

I have latest OneSignal SDK version:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/services/billing/onesignal-sdk-193316#publisher

Android manifest is basic:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting One Signal Debug to Verbose:

```
OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, 
OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
```

I've noticed that OneSignal can't open app due to permissions issue.
You need to set up special permissions for app manually on Special settings page.

After that notification works correctly: app opens on notification click.

Comment: I have verbose logging and don't see this permissions issue, but have the same problem. Can you share exactly what you mean by using a "Special settings page"? Where is this setting, and what did you change to make it work?